# Having a parent respond to a child's event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent object (a display window) and it has a few child objects (buttons and controls on the window). I would like one child object to hide itself when another is clicked. Currently, I have my parent object bind to a custom event expected to be fired from the child object. Then, the parent object passes the command on to its other child.

Example:

```
//Namespace for the 'Orders' page.
$(function Orders() {
    "use strict";
    var orders = $('#Orders');

    var ordersSearchResult = new OrdersSearchResult();
    var ordersSearchDisplay = new OrdersSearchDisplay();
    var ordersEditDisplay = new OrdersEditDisplay();

    ordersSearchResult.selector.bind('searchResultLinkClicked', function () {
        ordersEditDisplay.hide();
        ordersSearchDisplay.fadeIn();
    });
});
```

I have two questions / concerns about this code:

- I expose a property called 'selector' for `ordersSearchResult`. This is a direct reference to the jQuery DOM element. As I understand it this is bad practice -- objects should expose methods to affect their DOM elements, but not the DOM elements themselves. Previously, I passed the `onSearchResultLinkClicked` anonymous function into a method of `ordersSearchResult` which bound the event to the selector internally. I felt that that implementation was counter-intuitive, though, as it did not read very clearly to see anonymous functions being passed into 'binding' methods.
- `ordersEditDisplay` and `ordersSearchDisplay` expose methods `hide()` and `fadeIn()` which affect their DOM elements, but `ordersEditDisplay`/`ordersSearchDisplay` are **not** DOM elements themselves. Is it bad practice to 'confuse' other developers like this? The code could read: `ordersEditDisplay.selector.hide()` but I did not want to expose the selector publically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really hard to judge if exposing `selector` is the *"right"* thing to do without reviewing more of your source code.
Also, it depends on your architecture design. If you're using a [Model View Controller](http://www.phpzag.com/php-model-view-controller-mvc/) approach, then yes. Elements associated with the view will be exposed.
Check out some of the examples for [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View).

Here are some other factors that come into play:

- Coding standards
- size of your source
- how strictly you're required to follow Object Oriented Programming, OOP.
- who will maintain your code.

The code you provided looks great. As long as you produce consistent readable code that has a good level of data abstraction and **works**, then you shouldn't worry about the small details.

If you're still concerned about it though then just create an adapter for the `.bind()`.

Old Code:

```
ordersSearchResult.selector.bind('searchResultLinkClicked', function () {
    ordersEditDisplay.hide();
    ordersSearchDisplay.fadeIn();
});
```

New Code:

```
...
OrdersSearchResult.prototype.bind = function(eventName, fn ){
    this.selector.bind( eventName, fn );
};
...
var ordersSearchResult = new OrdersSearchResult();
ordersSearchResult.bind('searchResultLinkClicked', function () {
    ordersEditDisplay.hide();
    ordersSearchDisplay.fadeIn();
});
```

Here are a few additional tips.

### 1) Name variables and properties based on their overall purpose and type.

> Programmer A: There's a problem with orders in your code.
> Programmer B: Which one? Are you talking about the function, jQuery object, element id, or something else?

To avoid this situation, create unique names assuming the language is case insensitive.

Old code:

```
$(function Orders() {
    "use strict";
    var orders = $('#Orders');
    ...
```

New code:

```
$(function OrdersFunc() {
    "use strict";
    var $orders = $('#OrdersTable');
    ...
```

More info here: ["How to name variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203618/how-to-name-variables)

### 2) Add the dollar sign as a prefix for jQuery variables.

It would make more sense to rename `selector` as `$el`.

### 3) Try not to create method names that are the same from a different library API.

`ordersEditDisplay.hide()` sounds like `ordersEditDisplay` returns a jQuery object, but that isn't the case.
Instead of `ordersEditDisplay.hide();`, try `ordersEditDisplay.hideView();`

### 4) Use the Singleton Pattern or an object literal to create a namespace.

Great examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635800/javascript-best-singleton-pattern)

### Final Code:

```
var mySite = {};
mySite.Orders = {};
mySite.Orders.init = function() {
    "use strict";
    var $orders = $('#OrdersTable');

    var ordersSearchResult = new OrdersSearchResult();
    var ordersSearchDisplay = new OrdersSearchDisplay();
    var ordersEditDisplay = new OrdersEditDisplay();

    ordersSearchResult.$el.bind('searchResultLinkClicked', function () {
        ordersEditDisplay.hideView();
        ordersSearchDisplay.fadeInView();
    });
};
$(mySite.Orders.init);
```

Comment: I appreciate your thorough response. Parts of it I have applied to my code, but I can't help but feel that the final code has changed stylistically, but not structurally. While it is more clear that a jQuery element is exposed -- the true issue hasn't been resolved. Is it standard to expose jQuery elements publicly from objects? It does not seem that way to me. I think the hideView over hide suggestion is a very strong improvement. Naming standards are always tricky, but I definitely appreciate the points you've made.

Comment: @SeanAnderson Updated my answer.